# php - remove nth character from last in string

Tags: php, string

How to remove specific character ',' from String from last index if exist.Is it possible to remove ?

```
{ "messages": [
    {
        "a": "a",
        "a": "",
        "a": "Title : Test Image",
        "a": "+923346455485"
    },{
        "a": "a",
        "a": "",
        "a": "Title : Test Image",
        "a": "+923346455485"
    },
]}
```

I want to remove last comma only from the string... which is `},]}` I want to remove the comma only..

**I have tried this :**

```
echo substr(trim($resultstr), 0, -4);
```

but it removes all the 4 characters from last.

Comment: Why? It's json. There is no need to remove it.

Comment: How did it get there in the first place…?

Comment: This isn't valid JSON. If it were, I am pretty sure you would need to convert it to a string before substr() will work.

Comment: @Andreas the last `,` makes it invalid json

Comment: True, it does make it invalid. I thought json_decode could handle it, but I guess not.

Comment: It's not just the comma, there are duplicate keys.

Comment: Thanks for all of the contributions... I have fixed my code and output.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a regular expression. Something like `/\},(\s+)\]/m` should work.

```
$data = preg_replace('/\},(\s+)\]/m', '}$1]', $data);
```

But instead of fixing this part, you should fix the code, which generates the wrong `,` inside the json string.

Comment: `m` makes no sense if there is no `^` or `$` in the pattern.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
$str = '{"messages":[{"a":"a","a":"","a":"Title : Test Image","a":"+923346455485"},{"a":"a","a":"","a":"Title : Test Image","a":"+923346455485"},]}';

if (!empty(strrpos($str, '"},]'))) {
    $str[strrpos($str, ',', strrpos($str, '"},]'))] = '';
}

echo $str;
```

But I strictly advise against this and suggest you to replace the code where this string is formed in the Backend assuming you are trying to construct a JSON string.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try:

```
$string = substr_replace($string, '', strrpos($string, ','), 1);
```